# Android Audio Playback Issue

Tags: android, audio, android-alertdialog

I am playing some sound/audio when an alertbox is displayed.

I want to handle the case which is when I press the Positive or negative button of Alertdialog, IF the audio is not completed by that time, I want the audio to stop playing.

How to handle this specific condition?

Code:

```
        AlertDialog.Builder alertdialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                Activity.this);
        alertdialog.setTitle("Title ");
        alertdialog.setMessage("The MEssage ");


        LayoutInflater layoutinf= LayoutInflater.from(Activity.this);
        final View view = layoutinf.inflate(R.layout.layoutfile, null);
        alertdialog.setView(view);
        alertdialog.setPositiveButton("Button1",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int which) {
                        //do something 
                    }
                });
        alertdialog.show();

                MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.file_to_play);
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.release();
                    }

                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should be fine in your case .

```
      AlertDialog.Builder alertdialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                Activity.this);
        alertdialog.setTitle("Title ");
        alertdialog.setMessage("The MEssage ");

        final  MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.file_to_play);
        LayoutInflater layoutinf= LayoutInflater.from(Activity.this);
        final View view = layoutinf.inflate(R.layout.layoutfile, null);
        alertdialog.setView(view);
        alertdialog.setPositiveButton("Button1",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int which) {
                        if( mp !=null && mp.isPlaying()){
                                 mp.stop();
                           }
                    }
                });
        alertdialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

          @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
              if( mp !=null && mp.isPlaying()){
                           mp.stop();
                        }                       
    }
         });
        alertdialog.show();


                mp.start();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.release();
                    }

                });
```

Comment: Should we release also after stopping it ?